# How to create multiple turtles in certain patches of the world quickly using NetLogo 6.2?

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to solve a problem of speed in creating turtles in the NetLogo world.

I have a model that has a world with a size of 600X600. I, too, have 31 turtle profiles (each turtle can only born in a specific habitatcover type or habitatcover set (see ValidHabs variable in the code). In the code, too, there are 2 variables that are metabolism with 2 levels (list1 in the code) and reproduction with 2 levels (list2 in the code). Also, I would like to have at least 200 turtles born in the world or more in this world.

The problem is that it is taking a long time for turtles to be born in the world. Have I already created a switch called Display? to speed up the creation of the turtles. I also set it to faster speed and it still takes a long time to create the turtles.

Does anyone know how I can speed up the creation of turtles based on my code?

I don't know what else to do to speed up the code... I appreciate any kind of help :)

Thanks in advance

The code below:

```
globals [ ValidHabs  ValidHabsItem HotPatchSet CurrentHotPatchSet ]

patches-own [ habitatcover ]

turtles-own [ turtle-profiles-habitat metabolism reproduction all-code code-metabolism code-reproduction ]

to setup
  clear-all
  random-seed 1
  ;; ValidHabs are the habitat profiles of the turtles are all combinations of 5 types of habitatcover without repetition
  set ValidHabs [[1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [1 2] [1 3] [1 4] [1 5] [2 3] [2 4] [2 5] [3 4] [3 5] [4 5] [1 2 3] [1 2 4] [1 2 5] [1 3 4] [1 3 5] [1 4 5] [2 3 4] [2 3 5] [2 4 5] [3 4 5] [1 2 3 4] [1 2 3 5] [1 2 4 5] [1 3 4 5] [2 3 4 5] [1 2 3 4 5]]
  ifelse ( Display? = true ) [ display ] [ no-display ] ;; display is a switch in interface
  resize-world 599 * 0 ( 599 * 1 )  ( 599 * -1 ) 599 * 0 ;; the world is 600X600 in size
  setup-world
  setup-patches
  reset-ticks
  print ( word "That setup took " timer " seconds" )
end

to setup-world
  let pcolors []
  set pcolors [ 25 65 23 53 105 10 ]
  ask patches [
    set pcolor item (random 5) pcolors
  ]

  ask patches [
    if pcolor = 25 [ set habitatcover 1 ]
    if pcolor = 65 [ set habitatcover 2 ]
    if pcolor = 23 [ set habitatcover 3 ]
    if pcolor = 53 [ set habitatcover 4 ]
    if pcolor = 105 [ set habitatcover 5 ]
    if pcolor = 10 [ set habitatcover 6 ]
  ]
end

to setup-patches
  set-patch-size 0.6 ;; view patch size
  set HotPatchSet patches with  [ ( habitatcover != 6 ) ]
  let list1 ( list 2 4 )
  let list2 ( list 5 10 )
  let n0 count turtles
  set CurrentHotPatchSet HotPatchSet with [ habitatcover = one-of item ValidHabsItem ValidHabs ]
  while [ n0 < ( length list1 ) * ( length list2 ) * 200 ] ;; I want 200 ou more turtles in the word. Here I put 200
  [
    (
      foreach list1
      [
        this-metabolism ->
        foreach list2
        [
          this-reproduction ->
          let c count CurrentHotPatchSet
          if c = 0 [ stop ]
          ask one-of CurrentHotPatchSet
          [
            sprout 1
            [
              set turtle-profiles-habitat item ValidHabsItem ValidHabs
              set metabolism this-metabolism
              set reproduction this-reproduction
              setup-turtles who
            ]
            set CurrentHotPatchSet CurrentHotPatchSet with [ not any? turtles in-radius 2 ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    )
    set n0 count turtles
  ]
end

to setup-turtles [ whichTurtle? ]
  set color black
  ask turtle who [
    (
      ifelse
      metabolism = 2 [set code-metabolism "M1"]
      metabolism = 4 [set code-metabolism "M2"]
    )
    (
      ifelse
      reproduction = 5 [set code-reproduction "R1"]
      reproduction = 10 [set code-reproduction "R2"]
    )
    set all-code ( word code-metabolism code-reproduction )
  ]
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid I did not look for the particular problems in your code, but there is general advice on speeding up models here:
http://jasss.soc.surrey.ac.uk/20/1/3.html
with updates here:
http://www.railsback-grimm-abm-book.com/jasss-models/

I'm pretty sure that some of the advice applies to your code.

Comment: Thanks Steve R. :)

Comment: Hi Steve. Just a quick editor's note about signatures. We don't add them on Stack Overflow - the profile card is thought to be sufficient for this. Where they are seen, editors tend to remove them, so it would save us some bother if they weren't added. Thanks!